# Is there an IDE that provides code completion for Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino

I have tried almost every IDE listed [here](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/getting-setup.php), but none of them provide code completion.
As a Flex developer I am used to code completion in Flash Builder. It saves tons of time and helps with spelling errors.
Does anybody know about IDE with code completion for Cappuccino? Is is difficult to create, or it is simply not as important for everybody as it is important for me?

Our company is gonna use Cappuccino heavily, and thus I don't mind to ask one developer to volunteer and create some kind of Eclipse plugin. Just let me know, how important it is and how difficult it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no full IDE support that I know of, but several text editors have support. Coda ships with it, and there exist textmate and sublime text plugins (Several of the core team members use Sublime, and I hear it's pretty good.) https://github.com/aparajita/Cappuccino-Sublime

Also, unfortunately, the website is a pretty poor resource for finding relevant content, it works for some old stuff that hasn't changed (like the tutorials), but things like debugging and editors the info is almost certainly out of date because of how rapidly these things are changing.